# Canvas.Context Restore on mousemove is failing HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a hover effect for a canvas image when a mousemove over the  image, a transparent overlay shows up. Once a user mouseout am trying to restore the canvas back to it initial stage by making use of the Canvas restore method but it keeps failing. Below is the whole code

```
    var images = [];
    var halfCircle;
    var ctx;
    var canvas;
    var effect = true;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        canvas.style.backgroundColor = '#fafafa';

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        halfCircle = new HalfCircle();
        halfCircle.doArch(ctx);
        placeImages(ctx);
        addEventListenersToCanvas(canvas, ctx);
    });

    function placeImages(ctx){
        first_image = new Image();
        first_image.src = 'http://example.com/media/features/0.png';
        first_image.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(first_image, 20, 20);
            images.push({x:20,y:20,link: "http://example.com/shoppinglist-infographic", img : first_image});
            ctx.save();
        }
        second_image = new Image();
        second_image.src = "http://example.com/media/features/1.png";
        second_image.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(second_image, 130, 150);
            images.push({x:130,y:150,link: "http://example.com/referral/invite?g=banner", img : second_image});
            ctx.save();
        }
        third_image = new Image();
        third_image.src = "http://example.com/media/features/2.png";
        third_image.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(third_image, 230, 220);
            images.push({x:230,y:220,link: "http://example.com/all-fast-delivery/", img : third_image});
            ctx.save();
        }
        fourth_image = new Image();
        fourth_image.src = "http://example.com/media/features/3.png";
        fourth_image.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(fourth_image,460, 220);
            images.push({x:460,y:220,link:"http://example.com/busyhomemaker/", img : fourth_image});
            ctx.save();

        }
        fifth_image = new Image();
        fifth_image.src = "http://example.com/media/features/4.png";
        fifth_image.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(fifth_image,570, 150);
            images.push({x:570,y:150,link:"#", img: fifth_image});
            ctx.save();
        }
        sixth_image = new Image();
        sixth_image.src = "http://example.com/media/features/5.png";
        sixth_image.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(sixth_image,620, 20);
            images.push({x:620,y:20,link:"#", img:sixth_image});
            ctx.save();
        }
        text_image = new Image();
        text_image.src = "http://example.com/media/features/text.png";
        text_image.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(text_image,285, 20);
            ctx.save();
        }

    }

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }
    function addEventListenersToCanvas(canvas, ctx){
        ctx.save();
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
            for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
                if(    (mousePos.x > images[i].x) && (mousePos.x < (images[i].x + images[i].img.width)) &&
                        (mousePos.y > images[i].y) && (mousePos.y < (images[i].y + images[i].img.height))
                ){

                    document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
                    if(effect) {
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#fafafa";
                        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
                        ctx.fillRect(images[i].x, images[i].y, images[i].img.width, images[i].img.height);
                        effect = false;
                    }
                }else{
                    document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
                    ctx.restore();
                    effect = true;
                }

            }

        });
       //
        canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, event);
            for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
                if(
                        (mousePos.x > images[i].x) && (mousePos.x < images[i].x + images[i].img.width) &&
                        (mousePos.y > images[i].y) && (mousePos.y < images[i].y + images[i].img.height)
                ){
                   // console.log('clicking on: ' + images[i].link);
                    window.open(images[i].link);

                }
            }

        });
    }

    var HalfCircle = function(){
        this.numOfArch = 6;
        this.posX = 438;
        this.posY = 20;
        this.rad = 170;
        this.color = [
            { start_color: 'rgb(255,182,54)', end_color: 'rgb(255,220,159)' },
            { start_color: 'rgb(240,97,38)', end_color: 'rgb(249,166,57)' },
            { start_color: 'rgb(254,107,108)', end_color: 'rgb(250,74,78)' },
            { start_color: 'rgb(0,131,195)', end_color: 'rgb(0,150,219)' },
            { start_color: 'rgb(115,174,14)', end_color: 'rgb(214,243,137)' },
            { start_color: 'rgb(133,29,250)', end_color: 'rgb(203,159, 255)' },
        ];
        this.lineWidth = 5;
    };

    HalfCircle.prototype = {
        smallDot: function (posX, posY, ctx, colr){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = colr;
            ctx.arc(posX, posY, 7, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        },
        bigDot : function (posX, posY, ctx, colr){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = colr;
            ctx.arc(posX, posY, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        },
        getEndCord: function(startCord){
            return startCord + Math.PI/this.numOfArch;
        },
        doArch : function (ctx){
            var startCord = 0;
            for( i = 0; i < this.numOfArch; i++ ){
                dotStartX = this.rad * Math.cos(startCord) + this.posX;
                dotStartY = this.rad * Math.sin(startCord) + this.posY;
                this.smallDot(dotStartX, dotStartY, ctx , this.color[i].start_color);
                ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.strokeStyle = this.color[i].start_color;
                var endCord = this.getEndCord(startCord);
                ctx.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.rad, startCord, endCord , false);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
                startCord = endCord;
                dotStartX = this.rad * Math.cos(endCord) + this.posX;
                dotStartY = this.rad * Math.sin(endCord) + this.posY;
                this.bigDot(dotStartX, dotStartY, ctx , this.color[i].end_color);
            }
        }

    }
```

Am seriously would need someone input on these. Thanks

Comment: `context.save` only saves the context state (stylings, transformations, etc). It does not save anything you have drawn on the canvas. So `context.restore` will only restore the context state, not the drawings. To remove something you have previously drawn on the canvas, you must clear the entire canvas and redraw everything that you do want on the canvas.

Comment: @markE what do u think will be the best approach to achieve what am trying to do?? Thanks for the response too really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.save` only saves the context state (stylings, transformations, etc). It does not save anything you have drawn on the canvas. So `context.restore` will only restore the context state, not the drawings.

To remove something you have previously drawn on the canvas, you must clear the entire canvas and redraw everything that you do want on the canvas.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

//
var halfCircle;
var effect = true;
var overlayIndex=-1;
//
var images = [];
images.push({x:20,y:20,  link: "http://example.com/shoppinglist-infographic"});
images.push({x:130,y:150,link: "http://example.com/referral/invite?g=banner"});
images.push({x:230,y:220,link: "http://example.com/all-fast-delivery/"});
images.push({x:460,y:220,link:"http://example.com/busyhomemaker/"});
images.push({x:570,y:150,link:"#"});
images.push({x:620,y:20, link:"#"});
images.push({x:285,y:20, link:"#"});


// Define HalfCircle
var HalfCircle = function(){
    this.numOfArch = 6;
    this.posX = 438;
    this.posY = 20;
    this.rad = 170;
    this.color = [
        { start_color: 'rgb(255,182,54)', end_color: 'rgb(255,220,159)' },
        { start_color: 'rgb(240,97,38)', end_color: 'rgb(249,166,57)' },
        { start_color: 'rgb(254,107,108)', end_color: 'rgb(250,74,78)' },
        { start_color: 'rgb(0,131,195)', end_color: 'rgb(0,150,219)' },
        { start_color: 'rgb(115,174,14)', end_color: 'rgb(214,243,137)' },
        { start_color: 'rgb(133,29,250)', end_color: 'rgb(203,159, 255)' },
    ];
    this.lineWidth = 5;
};
//
HalfCircle.prototype = {
    smallDot: function (posX, posY, ctx, colr){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = colr;
        ctx.arc(posX, posY, 7, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    },
    bigDot : function (posX, posY, ctx, colr){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = colr;
        ctx.arc(posX, posY, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    },
    getEndCord: function(startCord){
        return startCord + Math.PI/this.numOfArch;
    },
    doArch : function (ctx){
        var startCord = 0;
        for( i = 0; i < this.numOfArch; i++ ){
            dotStartX = this.rad * Math.cos(startCord) + this.posX;
            dotStartY = this.rad * Math.sin(startCord) + this.posY;
            this.smallDot(dotStartX, dotStartY, ctx , this.color[i].start_color);
            ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.color[i].start_color;
            var endCord = this.getEndCord(startCord);
            ctx.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.rad, startCord, endCord , false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            startCord = endCord;
            dotStartX = this.rad * Math.cos(endCord) + this.posX;
            dotStartY = this.rad * Math.sin(endCord) + this.posY;
            this.bigDot(dotStartX, dotStartY, ctx , this.color[i].end_color);
        }
    }
}

// preload all images
// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push('http://example.com/media/features/0.png');
imageURLs.push('http://example.com/media/features/1.png');
imageURLs.push('http://example.com/media/features/2.png');
imageURLs.push('http://example.com/media/features/3.png');
imageURLs.push('http://example.com/media/features/4.png');
imageURLs.push('http://example.com/media/features/5.png');
imageURLs.push('http://example.com/media/features/text.png');
//
// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
startLoadingAllImages(imagesAreNowLoaded);
//
// Create a new Image() for each item in imageURLs[]
// When all images are loaded, run the callback (==imagesAreNowLoaded)
function startLoadingAllImages(callback){
  // iterate through the imageURLs array and create new images for each
  for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
    // create a new image an push it into the imgs[] array
    var img = new Image();
    imgs.push(img);
    // when this image loads, call this img.onload
    img.onload = function(){ 
      // this img loaded, increment the image counter
      imagesOK++; 
      // if we've loaded all images, call the callback
      if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    // notify if there's an error
    img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    // set img properties
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}
//
function imagesAreNowLoaded(){
  // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
  // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]
  halfCircle = new HalfCircle();
  draw();
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
}

function draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle='#fafafa';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    halfCircle.doArch(ctx);
    for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
        ctx.drawImage(imgs[i], images[i].x,images[i].y);        
        if(i==overlayIndex){
            ctx.fillStyle = "#fafafa";
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.35;
            ctx.fillRect( images[i].x, images[i].y, imgs[i].width, imgs[i].height);
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1.00;
        }
    }
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  //
  overlayIndex=-1;
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
      var img=images[i];
      var image=imgs[i];
      if(
          mx>img.x && mx<img.x+image.width &&
          my>img.y && my<img.y+image.height
      ){
          overlayIndex=i;
      }
  }
  draw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=900 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: you are the best really but what if i want to add a shadow instead of an overlay?

Comment: @omoabobade. Sure. Then use `context.shadowColor` to draw a shadow instead of an overlay. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

hope it will helps you..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Canvas Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<header> </header>
<nav> </nav>
<section>

<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="200">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var ctx;

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
draw();
}


function draw() {

ctx.fillStyle = '#FA6900';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 4;
ctx.shadowColor   = 'rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5)';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,15,150);
ctx.save();

ctx.fillStyle = '#E0E4CD';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 10;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 4;
ctx.shadowColor   = 'rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5)';
ctx.fillRect(30,0,30,150);
ctx.save();

ctx.fillStyle = '#A7DBD7';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 15;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 4;
ctx.shadowColor   = 'rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5)';
ctx.fillRect(90,0,45,150);
ctx.save();

ctx.restore();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(185, 75, 22, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.restore();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(260, 75, 15, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.restore();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(305, 75, 8, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
}

init();
</script>
</section>
<aside> </aside>
<footer> </footer>
</body>
</html>
```